# HTML scroll-snap doesn't work when a css animation is playing

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a page with scroll snapping, and a css animation.
The scroll snapping works fine, except with a css animation playing.
When css animation isn't playing, the scroll snapping scrolls smoothly, but when it plays, it scrolls instantly, which is not smooth.
Anybody knows why this happens and how to fix it?

```css
:root {
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #3f5060;
    --red: #e2403d;
    --orange: #ef9325;
    --blue: #3fa4dc;

    --darken-50: #b0b0b066;
    --darken-75: #b0b0b0aa;

    --background: #3f5060;
    --font: #ffffff;
    --header: #000000;
    --header-button: #000000;
    --header-button-hover: #ef9325;
    --button-color: #ef9325;
    --button-color-hover: #ffa335;
}
.section {position:absolute;left:0px;height:100%;width:100%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;scroll-snap-align: start;}
.decor-box-orange {background-color:var(--orange);position:absolute}
html {
    background-color: var(--background);
    font-family: medium;
    color: var(--font);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
@keyframes section2decorbox {
    0% {left:-100%;}
    10% {left:-100%;}
    30% {left:0%;}
    70% {left:0%;}
    90% {left:100%;}
    100% {left:100%;}
}

@keyframes section2decorbox2 {
    0% {left:100%;}
    10% {left:100%;}
    30% {left:0%;}
    70% {left:0%;}
    90% {left:-100%;}
    100% {left:-100%;}
}
```

```html
<section class="section" style="top:0px;overflow: hidden;">
this is the 1st section    
</section>
<section class="section" style="top:100%;background:var(--blue);">
    <div style="animation:section2decorbox 10s alternate infinite;position:absolute;width:100%;height:10%;top:20%;z-index:1;" class="decor-box-orange"></div>
    <div style="animation:section2decorbox2 10s alternate infinite;position:absolute;width:100%;height:10%;top:70%;z-index:1;" class="decor-box-orange"></div>
    <h1 style="z-index:2;">H1</h1>
    <p style="width:50%;z-index:2;" align="center">P text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: share with code

Comment: done, its edited

Comment: check https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp

Comment: it actually works when the css animation isn't playing. but when the css animation is playing, it wouldn't work. btw, i do not want to use any js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting it from 
`scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;`
to 
`scroll-snap-type: y proximity;`
This didn't make the scroll instant and still smooth when snapped to another section when the css animation is playing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #3f5060;
    --red: #e2403d;
    --orange: #ef9325;
    --blue: #3fa4dc;

    --darken-50: #b0b0b066;
    --darken-75: #b0b0b0aa;

    --background: #3f5060;
    --font: #ffffff;
    --header: #000000;
    --header-button: #000000;
    --header-button-hover: #ef9325;
    --button-color: #ef9325;
    --button-color-hover: #ffa335;
}
.section {position:absolute;left:0px;height:100%;width:100%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;scroll-snap-align: start;}
.decor-box-orange {background-color:var(--orange);position:absolute}
html {
    background-color: var(--background);
    font-family: medium;
    color: var(--font);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
@keyframes section2decorbox {
    0% {left:-100%;}
    10% {left:-100%;}
    30% {left:0%;}
    70% {left:0%;}
    90% {left:100%;}
    100% {left:100%;}
}

@keyframes section2decorbox2 {
    0% {left:100%;}
    10% {left:100%;}
    30% {left:0%;}
    70% {left:0%;}
    90% {left:-100%;}
    100% {left:-100%;}
}
```

```html
<section class="section" style="top:0px;overflow: hidden;">
this is the 1st section    
</section>
<section class="section" style="top:100%;background:var(--blue);">
    <div style="animation:section2decorbox 10s alternate infinite;position:absolute;width:100%;height:10%;top:20%;z-index:1;" class="decor-box-orange"></div>
    <div style="animation:section2decorbox2 10s alternate infinite;position:absolute;width:100%;height:10%;top:70%;z-index:1;" class="decor-box-orange"></div>
    <h1 style="z-index:2;">H1</h1>
    <p style="width:50%;z-index:2;" align="center">P text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Ill try! Thanks!

Comment: verify answer when it's helpful or true

Comment: i tried this, and it didnt work. it still scrolls without smooth scroll animation when the css animation is playing.

Comment: compare your question my answer

Comment: It doesnt change much, and sometimes it doesn't even snap